# Using ora_rowscn to know of each change

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to track all the changes on a table in oracle11g, using my java application.

I am thinking about using the `ora_rowscn` like this: performing a select and each time getting more recent records:

```java
max = 0;

While(true){

   ps = con.prepare statement("Select rowscn, * from t where  ora_rowscn > ?");

   ps.setInt(max);

   max = calcMaxRowScn(ps.getResultSet());

}
```

`calcMaxRowScn` - returns maximum rowscn from the result set.

Oracle docs state:

`"ORA_ROWSCN returns the conservative upper bound system change number (SCN) of the most recent change to the row"`

So:

1. Is using the rowscn field safe?
2. Is it possible that I might miss some updates?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't miss any updates (you'll obviously miss any deletes).  You may see the `ORA_ROWSCN` for a row change even though no change has actually been made, particularly when the table was not built with `ROWDEPENDENCIES` enabled because by default the SCN is stored at the block level not the row level.  So long as your application can handle processing rows that haven't changed, that should be fine.  Of course, since `ORA_ROWSCN` is not indexed, you'd be full scanning the table every time through the loop in Java-- that could very easily end up being rather slow and put a rather large load on the database server.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, there may be an easier option.  For example, you may want to use something like [Continuous Query Notification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_cqn.htm) instead of rolling your own.